# why the way to call asynchronous is wrong?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise

```js
  const before = () => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // resolve('before')
      console.log("ok");
      reject(new Error("error!!!"));
    });
    return p;
  };

  const handleClick = () => {
    const p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(true);
    });
    p.then(() => {
      before();
    })
      // .then(before)
      // .then(async () => {
      //   await before();
      // })
      .then(() => {
        console.log("then");
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
  };
```

The above three ways to call 'before' function, the last two ways could catch the exception but not the first one, why and what's the execution sequence of the above code?

Comment: also the commented `await before();` approach was good

Comment: You need to return the `before()`. Right now the function returns nothing, hence no error.

Comment: Why not use `await` instead?

Comment: why the return is necessary to catch the exception

Comment: There is no exception. `before` is just a rejected promise. If you don't return it, then nothing at all happens with it. Having a rejected promise you don't act on, does not affect anything else in the code.